# First instance of activity never gets garbage collected?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm investigating whether my Android activity has a memory leak using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT). If the activity has a leak, I would expect dead instances to be hanging around on the heap, not getting garbage collected. To check this, I repeatedly start and stop (by pressing the Back button) the activity, and then inspect heap dumps using the MAT.

But I'm observing some strange behaviour that I cannot explain: the very first instance of the activity (started after a having done a force close) never gets garbage collected. However, subsequent instances do. I know this from inspection using the MAT tool: no matter how many times the activity is started and stopped, the MAT tool always shows two instances on the heap. The first instance belongs to the very first time the activity was started, while the second instance belongs to the most recently run activity.

Any idea as to what may be happening, and whether I should be worried about this wrt. memory leaks? Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: There might be something that's holding on to the original instance of your activity, either to the actual activity or a variable defined within. You can check what is referencing the activity using MAT, on of the views lets you trace it.

Comment: Specifically you want to trace the GC roots to see what's holding onto it.

Comment: Thanks for both of those comments. There is a lot holding on to the activity, mainly member objects. But doing an "exclude weak/soft references" seems to boil it down to an Android mapping component. My activity is a subclass of MapActivity. The stale activity object seems to be referenced by android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapFlashService. Maybe this is a known issue - I'll look into it.

Comment: I would not be the least bit surprised to see that Maps V1 holds an indirect static reference to the one-and-only `MapActivity` instance that you are allowed.

Comment: Yes - seems that there are known issues with memory leaks in MapActivity subclasses. See e.g. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2181. Haven't found a fix that works for me yet. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @MichaelPedersen please put in as answer and close post.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close: seems that there are known issues with memory leaks in MapActivity subclasses. See e.g. code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2181. Haven't found a fix that works for me yet.